# Error while ItemsControl on Image Type

Tags: c#, wpf

what type of list do we need to have in order to Bind Sources of Images using ItemsControl. I have an itemsControl like this :

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="championPicControl" Margin="10,0,516,63">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="100" Width="100"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And it gets me an error when i do :

```
        List<BitmapImage> list = new List<BitmapImage>();
        foreach(var i in summsList)
        {
            BitmapImage champ = new BitmapImage();
            champ.BeginInit();
            champ.UriSource = new Uri("Resources/championsSquare/" + i.championName + "_Square_0.png", UriKind.Relative);
            champ.EndInit();
            list.Add(champ);
        }

        championPicControl.ItemsSource = list;
```

What type of list and what should i do in order to get it work ?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I see 2 potential problem in your code:
For embedded resources better use UriKind.Absolute `pack://application:,,,/[YourAssemblyName];component/Resources/{Y‌​ourImageName}.`
You need use ObservableCollection instead of List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource file URIs in code behind have to be full [Resource File Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly). So you should create the BitmapImages like

```
var champ = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/Resources/championsSquare/" + i.championName + "_Square_0.png"));
```

Besides that it isn't strictly necessary to use a List of BitmapImages. WPF provides automatic type conversion from `string`, `Uri` and `byte[]` to type `ImageSource` (the type of the `Image.Source` property).

So you could as well assign an `IEnumerable<string>` with the resource URI strings to the ItemsControl's `ItemsSource` property.

```
championPicControl.ItemsSource = summsList.Select(
    i => "pack://application:,,,/Resources/championsSquare/" + i.championName + "_Square_0.png");
```